# Не могу понять, почему ругается компилятор

Tags: c++

Решил попробовать создать двоичный тип данных для вводимых чисел, а также функции конъюнктирования и дизъюнктирования к ним. Однако в какой-то момент что-то пошло не так.

[image: Выдает ошибку типа "Класс Binary не содержит подходящий конструктор копий."]

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>

struct Binary
{
private:
    std::string value;
    std::string to_binary(int number);
    std::string con(std::string value, std::string value_1);
    int to_int(std::string value);
public:
    Binary(int value_) :
        value(to_binary(value_))
    {
        //
    }
    Binary(Binary& type);
    Binary& operator= (Binary& type) {
        if (value == type.value) {
            return *this;
        }
        value = type.value;
        return *this;
    }
    Binary& operator+ (Binary& type){
        return Binary(to_int(con(value, type.value)));
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Binary& type);
};


Ошибка  C2440   return: невозможно преобразовать "Binary" в "Binary"     
Обучение заколовкам C:\Users\User\source\repos\Обучение заколовкам\Binary.h 29
```

Comment: Ругается именно компилятор, или анализатор? Если компилятор, то покажите что он говорит.

Comment: Невозможно преобразовать Binary в Binary

Comment: Выложите код текстом и код ошибки прикрепите.

Comment: @АресАресович добавьте слово const перед Binary в аргументах в конструкторе копирования

Comment: Вы поправили вопрос и теперь Ваш код будет падать во время выполнения. Отмените правку и верните код в прежнее состояние

Comment: спасибо, помогло. так, значит, необходимо const добавлять в большинстве случаев?

Comment: @АресАресович const нужно добавлять всегда когда Ваш код не будет изменять обьект

Comment: @АресАресович Код на скриншоте более корректный, чем тот, который Вы добавили позже

Comment: да, я понял и вернул все, а потом поставил const

Comment: Почему код на скришноте не совпадает с кодом в тексте? Там много не совпадающих ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что Ваш конструктор копирования обьявлен с параметром `Binary&`, а `operator+` возвращает обьект `Binary` по значению и для этого ему нужен конструктор копирования. Но `Binary(to_int(con(value, type.value)))` является **rvalue**, а не константная ссылка не может ссылаться на **rvalue**. Решение: обьявите конструктор копирования так:

```
Binary(const Binary& type);
```

Comment: благодарю за ответ, уже решили проблему

Answer (score 0):

1. И конструктор копирования, и оператор присваивания, и оператор `+`, и `operator<<` должны получать свои `Binary` параметры по *константной* ссылке.
2. Оператор `+` должен быть `const` сам по себе. А лучше было бы реализовать его самостоятельной [friend] функцией, а не методом класса.
3. Оператор присваивания обычно возвращает свой результат *по ссылке*, а оператор `+` должен возвращать свой результат *по значению*. Код на скриншоте в этом отношении не совпадает с кодом в тексте, т.е. видно, что вы метались туда-сюда, но но и там и там неправильно.
4. Проверка `if (value == type.value)` в операторе присваивания - бессмысленная трата времени и явная пессимизация. В данном случае проверка на самоприсваивание не нужна, но если вы хотите ее сделать, то это `if (this == &type)`.